# How to switch Orientation on PC platform like on mobile platform

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity Version:2021.2  PC:window10

I designed a scene 1080*1920, which is usually used in portrait displays, as shown below
[image]

Now I want to display it on a landscape 1920*1080 PC, as shown below[image]

I want to get the same effect as the mobile platform.What should I do? The premise is that I can't modify the UI already done.  How can I achieve this on the Pc platform?

I try Change CanvasScale but uselese.its easy on IOS or Android

Comment: Have you tried this https://answers.unity.com/questions/911755/portrait-build-on-pc.html ?

Comment: Probably in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432439/how-to-set-portrait-aspect-ratio-for-windows-build-in-unity

Comment: it is useless           。